# How to load a logged dictionary using MLflow?

Tags: python, databricks, mlflow

I successfully logged a pandas dataframe in dictionary format using MLflow with the following code:

```
df = <pd.DataFrame>
mlflow.log_dict(<pd.DataFrame>.to_dict(orient='dict'), f"my_logged_df_dict.json")
```

And now I attempted to read that logged dictionary and further investigate its content. Based on the documentation this should be easily achievable using the convenient `mlflow.artifacts.load_dict()` method. However, upon running this command, I get

```
AttributeError: module 'mlflow' has no attribute 'artifacts'
```

I checked my version which is 1.24.0. I checked the corresponding 1.24.0 feature branch on Github and I can see that the `artifacts` module does exist on this version and it does contain the method I am searching for. [Link to the Github module's `__init__`](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/1.24.0/mlflow/artifacts/__init__.py).

I am working on Databricks with the 10.4 Databricks ML Runtime which has the aforementioned version of mlflow pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

`mlflow.artifacts` was introduced in MLflow 1.25. It's not actually in 1.24: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/v1.24.0/mlflow/artifacts/__init__.py

I suspect you successfully logged with MLflow 1.25 or higher, and you are reading with MLflow 1.24 or lower.